# How what's the difference between "Filesystem and shell operations" and "Management Operations"

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, remote-debugging

I have I have configured Eclipse 2020-06 to deploy changed code to a Wildfly 20 Service running on a remote Ubuntu 20 VM (on a LAN).

In the Remote Server configuration I have "Management Operations" selected and I am able to deploy changes to the remote Wildfly server. However I chose this through trial and error.

What is the meaning of "Management Operations" and "Filesystem and shell operations" and how do you decided which to use when?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From JBoss Tools Documentation ([here](https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/configure_remote_server.html)):

> For the Controlled by field, select either the Filesystem and shell
> operations or Management Operations radio button option depending on
> your requirements.
>
> If you select Management Operations for the Controlled by field, you
> must set up an admin user on the server by using the
> $SERVER_HOME/bin/add-users.sh script (for Linux, or the
> $SERVER_HOME\bin\add-users.bat file for Windows) and enter the same
> credentials in the server editor or during the server start.